# preg_replace and regexp to get the domain

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a code which return the clean domain from HTTP_HOST

```
preg_replace('#^(.*\.)?(.*\..*)$#', '$2', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
```

But in case the domain is like somedomain.co.uk - it returns the co.uk only.
Can you pls help me to remake the RegExp to return the correct domain in this case?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Explain what you mean by “clean domain” to begin with.

Comment: from `www.somedomain.co.uk` you want to extract `uk` ?

Comment: I need to extract somedomain.co.uk

Comment: Can you add some examples to the question what should and what should not match? The pattern `^(.*\.)?(.*\..*)$` can be a very broad match.

Comment: _“I need to extract somedomain.co.uk”_ - from what? You mentioned HTTP_HOST - so you want to remove additional subdomains this might be prefixed with?

Comment: Would you please add some input examples, along with expected output ? We are actually only guessing what you want

Comment: I need to extract it from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: It is not my code, it is a free php shop

Comment: You will likely have to simply keep a _list_ of TLDs that deviate from the “usual” scheme. There is no other way to determine, whether `a.b.c.d` was a “normal” domain `c.d` with two subdomains, or a “special” domain `b.c.d` with one subdomain.

Comment: I see it works well in this mode:


if (!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $domains)) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
preg_replace('#^(https?:\/\/)?(www\d?\.)?([^\/\?]+)(.*)#', '$3', $url)
```

It works for the following cases:

```
<?php 

$urls = [
    'https://www.somedomain.co.uk', 
    'http://www.somedomain.co.uk', 
    'www.somedomain.co.uk/something', 
    'www.somedomain.co.uk?q=1',
    'www2.somedomain.co.uk/something',
    'somedomain.co.uk',
    '192.168.1.1/something?q=1&x=2',
];

foreach($urls as $url) {
    echo preg_replace('#^(https?:\/\/)?(www\d?\.)?([^\/\?]+)(.*)#', '$3', $url) . '<br>';
}
```